# Python Regular exp to match superscript 2

Tags: python, regex

I have a text with a lot of I²C and I want to change the super 2. According to what I have read this should produce a match:

```
 m = re.search('\u00B2',text)
```

where text is a string with the text. M should not be none, but it is. what am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: how about `m = re.search(u'\u00B2',text)`

Comment: On my machine at least, the superscript 2 comes back as `\xfd`.  Would capturing for this work?

Comment: @Icodez whoa what encoding are you using? according to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fd/index.htm  .. there is no way superscript 2 should be \xfd  @user792589 what do you get if you type `repr(text)`

Comment: Yes!!! Joran Beasley!! That worked!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

you need to make the search string unicode by putting a u in front of it

```
m = re.search(u'\u00B2',text)
```